# Parse variable names in R vs Stata

Tags: r, loops, parsing, stata

I have a variable name family that only changes in the last four positions (years) and I would like to create variables addressing this family all at once.

In Stata I would simply do this:

```
forvalues n=1991(1)1995 {
gen comp`n’== (year_begin<`n’ & (year_end>`n’ | year_end==.))
}
```

Here’s what I’m doing in R:

```
data$comp1991<-ifelse(year(data$date_begin)<1991 & (year(data$date_end)>1991|is.na(data$date_end)),1,0)

data$comp1992<-ifelse(year(data$date_begin)<1992 & (year(data$date_end)>1992|is.na(data$date_end)),1,0)

data$comp1993<-ifelse(year(data$date_begin)<1993 & (year(data$date_end)>1993|is.na(data$date_end)),1,0)

data$comp1994<-ifelse(year(data$date_begin)<1994 & (year(data$date_end)>1994|is.na(data$date_end)),1,0)

data$comp1995<-ifelse(year(data$date_begin)<1995 & (year(data$date_end)>1995|is.na(data$date_end)),1,0)
```

So in Stata, I only have really one line of code, whereas in R, I need to repeat this line over and over, changing the `n’ manually.

Is there a way to do this more efficiently in R? (I am thinking some combination of a loop with eval(parse()) but not sure. Any ideas will be appreciated:

Comment: You can refer to (and create) column in data frames using `[[` as well at `$`, and the former supports character indices, as well as `paste`-ing together names of columns.

Comment: R also has loops, of course. The trick here is that you can also assign like `data[[ "comp1991" ]] <- val`. To construct `"comp1991"`, look at the `?paste0` documentation.

Comment: If [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35440235/324364) question is from a classmate of yours, you should really try to coordinate these things so you don't post the same question multiple time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on some of the comments, closest equivalent of the Stata loop you provided would be:

```
for(n in seq(1991, 1995)) {
    data[[paste0('comp', n)]] <- year(data$date_begin)<1991 & (year(data$date_end)>1991 | is.na(data$date_end))
}
```

The conditional statement will return zero and one in Stata, but FALSE and TRUE in R. There's no practical difference between the two though; you can still operate on them the same.

If you want to make the loop even *more* similar to the Stata code, you could clean up some of the repetitive references to the object `data` by using the `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
data <- data.table(data)
for(n in seq(1991, 1995)) {
    data[, paste0('comp',n) := year(date_begin)<1991 & (year(date_end)>1991 | is.na(date_end)]
}
```