# creating variables using loop or apply in r

Tags: r, for-loop, stata, sapply

I'm trying to create a series of variables in R based on an ifelse function:

```
comp1990<-ifelse(year_begin<1990 & year_end>1990,1,0)

comp1991<-ifelse(year_begin<1991 & year_end>1991,1,0)

comp1992<-ifelse(year_begin<1992 & year_end>1992,1,0)
```

I'm doing this for years 1970-2007.  Right now, I just have a line for every single year.

In stata, I could do this in the following way:

```
forvalues n=1970(1)2007 {

gen comp\`n'== (year_begin<\`n' & year_end>\`n')

}
```

Is there a similarly straightforward way to do this in **R**?  I know `for` loops aren't great.  Maybe using apply?

What I'm essentially doing is creating a dummy = 1 if a bank branch exists in year n and 0 otherwise (so if the bank branch was established before year n and if it closed after year n), which means it was operating in year n.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: A better question is why would you want to do this? This seems very odd

Comment: It would also be helpful to provide an explanation for nearly identical questions appearing in close succession by two different users: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35439914/324364

Comment: It looks like you are "partitioning" your data into chunks but I cannot understand why you want to do then. Can you please add desired processing logic for the data chunks so that we can find a better solution (*apply functions etc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
 sapply(1970:2007,function(x){ ifelse(year_begin<x & year_end>x,1,0) })
```

Comment: When needing a binary result, `as.integer(year_begin < x & year_end  > x)` will be much more efficient than `ifelse()` (just the integer values of the logical vector).

Comment: Awesome, thank you!!!! This did it.  Here's what the final code looks like: years<-c(1970,1980,1990,1991:2007)
yeardums<-data.frame(sapply(years,function(x){as.integer( year(bankall$date_begin)<x & (year(bankall$date_end)>x|is.na(bankall$date_end)))}))
yeardumnames<-sapply(years,function(x){paste("comp",x,sep="")})
names(yeardums)<-yeardumnames
bankall<-cbind(bankall,yeardums)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I managed to reach with the best to my understanding of the question. A better description of the data would be helpful.

Here is the data:

```
df<-data.frame(cbind(bank = c("bank1","bank2","bank3","bank4","bank5"), 
      year_begin = sample(1970:2007, 5, T),
      year_end = sample(1970:2007, 5, T) ))
df$year_begin<-as.numeric(as.character(df$year_begin))
df$year_end<-as.numeric(as.character(df$year_end))
```

I used two for loops to build variables names as well as values:

constructing the "comp+year" columns:

```
year<-c(1970:2007)
var<-list(length(year))
for(j in year){
    var[j-1969]<-paste('comp', j)
}
```

filling out the "comp+year" list:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
    for(j in year){
       if(df$year_begin[i] < j & df$year_end[i] > j) 
         {var[[j-1969]]<-c(var[[j-1969]], 1)} 
       else 
         {var[[j-1969]]<-c(var[[j-1969]], 0)}
  }
}
```

list to dataframe:

```
a<-do.call(rbind, var)
names<-a[,1]
values<-as.data.frame(t(a[,2:6]))
colnames(values)<-names
print(values)  #you can cbind this to your original dataframe
```